# Excel VBA to delete rows based on several criteria

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I have the following code

```
Dim CO_priority As String
Dim Col_ticketage As String

CO_priority = Range("Q4").Value
Col_ticketage = Range("Q5").Value

Sheets("Inc").Select
LR = Range("CO_priority" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = LR To 2 Step -1
    If (Range("CO_priority" & i).Value = "1" And Range("Col_ticketage" & i).Value < "1") Then Rows(i).delete
Next I
```

I would like this code to delete the rows if in Column given by the variable "CO_priority" value is 1 and in the column given by another variable "Col_ticketage" value is less than 1.

So lets say if the cell in Column A has the number 1 in it and Column B has a number smaller than 1 this row should be deleted, but in any other case the row should stay.

The code above for is deleting each and every line for some reason.

Could you tell me what's wrong with this code?

Comment: You have quotes around your variables... they won't be treated as variables. What is in `Range("Q4").value` and Q5 that you are storing in those two variables? What are you anticipating `Range("CO_priority" & i)` is going to rectify too?

Comment: okay, my bad I'm sorry perhaps another coffee would solve my problem. the solution is what you gave me "You have quotes around your variables... they won't be treated as variables." thank and sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A faster way will be using a `DelRng` to merge all rows that pass your 2-criteria, and then delete the entire range at once.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit           

Sub DelRows()

Dim CO_priority As String
Dim Col_ticketage As String
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
Dim DelRng As Range

CO_priority = Range("Q4").Value
Col_ticketage = Range("Q5").Value

With Sheets("Inc")
    LR = .Range(CO_priority & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LR To 2 Step -1
        If (.Range(CO_priority & i).Value = 1 And .Range(Col_ticketage & i).Value < 1) Then
            If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then
                Set DelRng = Application.Union(DelRng, .Rows(i))
            Else
                Set DelRng = .Rows(i)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With
' make sure DelRng is not nothing >> delete entire rows at one-shot
If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then DelRng.Delete

End Sub
```